# for_each with list of objects still cares about resource ordering

Tags: terraform

I have code that I've refactored from count to for_each, however since I'm using list(object) as the main variable I'm iterating on, whenever I try to add resources in the middle of the list the order still matters and TF wants to replace the objects.

My code:

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "dbs" {
  type = list(object({
    db_id   = string
    db_name = string
    labels  = map(string)
    iam_members = list(object({
      role   = string
      member = string
    }))
    tables = list(object({
      id          = string
      partitioned = string
      field       = string
      type        = string
      clustering  = optional(list(string))
    }))
    materialized_views = optional(list(object({
      id                  = string
      enable_refresh      = optional(string)
      refresh_interval_ms = optional(string)
    })))
    views = optional(list(object({
      id             = string
      use_legacy_sql = optional(string)
    })))

  }))
  description = "BigQuery Dataset to be created"
}
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "database" {
  for_each                   = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v }
  dataset_id                 = each.value.db_id
  friendly_name              = each.value.db_name
  description                = "Dataset created by Terraform"
  location                   = "US"
  delete_contents_on_destroy = var.delete_contents_on_destroy
  labels                     = each.value.labels
}

module "tables" {
  source   = "./tables"
  for_each = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v }
  db_id    = google_bigquery_dataset.database[each.key].dataset_id
  labels   = each.value.labels
  tables   = each.value.tables
}

module "materialized_views" {
  source             = "./materialized_views"
  for_each           = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v if v.materialized_views != null }
  db_id              = google_bigquery_dataset.database[each.key].dataset_id
  materialized_views = each.value.materialized_views
  labels             = each.value.labels
  depends_on         = [module.tables]
}

module "views" {
  source     = "./views"
  for_each   = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v if v.views != null }
  db_id      = google_bigquery_dataset.database[each.key].dataset_id
  views      = each.value.views
  labels     = each.value.labels
  depends_on = [module.tables]
}

module "iam" {
  source      = "./iam"
  for_each    = { for k, v in var.dbs : k => v }
  db_id       = google_bigquery_dataset.database[each.key].dataset_id
  iam_members = each.value.iam_members
}
```

**dev.tfvars:**

```
dbs = [
  {
    db_id   = "some_dataset1"
    db_name = "some_dataset1"
    labels = {
      environment = "dev"
    }
    iam_members = [
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
        member = "serviceAccount:1@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      },
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataOwner"
        member = "group:1@thebest.com"
      }
    ]
    tables = [
      {
        id          = "results"
        partitioned = "true"
        field       = "date_time_of_run"
        type        = "DAY"
      },
      {
        id          = "results_extended"
        partitioned = "true"
        field       = "date"
        type        = "DAY"
      }
    ]

    views = [
      {
        id             = "results_view"
        use_legacy_sql = "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    db_id   = "some_dataset3"
    db_name = "some_dataset3"
    labels = {
      environment = "dev"
    }
    iam_members = [
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
        member = "serviceAccount:1@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        member = "group:2@thebest.com",
        member = "group:3@thebest.com"

      },
    ]
    tables = [
      {
        id          = "daily_inventory"
        partitioned = "true"
        field       = "inventory_timestamp"
        type        = "DAY"
      }
    ]
    materialized_views = [
      {
        id                  = "inventory_materialized_view"
        enable_refresh      = "true"
        refresh_interval_ms = "1800000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    db_id   = "some_dataset2"
    db_name = "some_dataset2"
    labels = {
      environment = "dev"
    }
    iam_members = [
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
        member = "serviceAccount:1@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        member = "group:1@thebest.com",
        member = "group:1@thebest.com"
      }
    ]
    tables = []
  }
]
```

As you can see, some_dataset3 was inserted between some_dataset1 and some_dataset2.

Getting:

```
...
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

  # google_bigquery_dataset.database["1"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "database" {
~ dataset_id  = "some_dataset2" -> "some_dataset3" # forces replacement
....
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you converting from `list(object)` to `map(object)` instead of declaring it as `set(object)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of a list ("var.dbs") are identified by its index, therefore, when you insert an element in the middle of a list, it modifies a bunch of other elements' indexes resulting in resources being replaced.

**Solution #1**: try using a map instead of a list in "var.dbs" with a unique and unchanging key for each element which is then used to initialize resources.

**Solution #2**: keep the list data type for "var.dbs" as before, but avoid using its keys which is ephemeral. Instead, transform "var.dbs" list into a map where keys are constructed based on some property like "db_id" or "db_name".

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did, I refactored the for loop to be { for k in var.dbs : k.db_id => k } but now TF wants to destroy all of the existing resources and create them again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Would my only solution from this point be using moved blocks to move from the elements' indexes to named resources in the state?

Comment: I'm not seeing `{ for k in var.dbs : k.db_id => k }` in your code above. But if you changed it later, after initializing your resources, you'll have to move those resources to the new ID using the `moved` block, unless you're ok recreating them all from scratch. See [terraform docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/move-config#move-your-resources-with-the-moved-configuration-block)

Comment: Yes, I have changed it later and after some research saw that I cannot avoid it unfortunately. I will think of an automated way of using the moved blocks since it will be cumbersome to add them manually.

Comment: I see. How about these somewhat automated ways to move a bunch of resources:

**1.** Using a splat-like operator: `from = module.tables` (rather than `module.tables[0]` see [terraform refactoring](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring).

**2.** Write a python script that constructs and prints as many "moved" blocks as needed which is then copy-pasted to terraform configuration.

**3.** Using terraform cli: "terraform state mv" which is called for each resource manually or in a python script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will definitely check these options out.

Comment: Keep us posted!